# Docker MYSQL container exiting instantly with a volume

Tags: mysql, docker

Currently learning the Docker basics and I'm having trouble when running a MYSQL image that has a Volume configured.

I'm running an up to date version of *Docker Desktop for Mac* on macOS 10.14.3.

When running this is works fine:

`docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:8.0`

But when adding a `-v` option it connects and then exits immediately.

`docker run -d -v /Users/joebloggs/path/to/my/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:8.0`

I've tried all major versions of the official *mysql* image.

Here's part of a `docker inspect` dump:

```
"State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 1,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-03-26T13:41:29.106885548Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-03-26T13:41:31.48468934Z"
        },
```

And the `Mounts` section:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/joebloggs/path/to/my/data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Don't use -d (--detached) mode straight away, use -it instead and check the output to see what it is saying.

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker logs container_id` command? Also, please make sure the last container running on port 3306 is stopped before running another container at at this port.

Comment: are you sure you want to bind volume to `data:/var/lib/mysql` ? that is full of mysql files and directories. Why do you need to bind your volume there?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/deploy-mysql-nonlinux-docker.html

i guess this is where that weird behavior comes from. im also having troubles with mysql container on mac.

Comment: @Efrat Thanks for the link. Seems the mysql image on non-linux environments  needs a bit of hand holding. I tried the same approach but using the MariaDB official image (10.2) and it worked first time. Think I'll see how that goes for now.

Comment: have you tried mysql:5 instead of 8? i think this one is less problematic

Comment: @Efrat I've definitely tried a couple of images. Might try the oldest available just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Though according to your command, the misplaced parameters could be the cause;
Use this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively just set up the docker-compose.yml